# Как исправить QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql

Не могу исправить ошибку запроса. В общем смысле, есть метод, который по расписанию выполняет действия с бд. и есть запрос вида:

```
@Query(value = "select u from UserBirthday u where date_trunk('month', u.bornDate) - interval '1 month' < now() and u.status = 'ACTIVE')
List<UserBirthday> getUsersBirthday();
```

получаю ошибку QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: index: near line 1... при этом запрос вида:

```
@Query(value = "select u from UserBirthday u where date_part('day', age(now(),u.bornDate)) < 30 and u.status = 'ACTIVE')
List<UserBirthday> getUsersBirthday();
```

не вызывает исключения, но отрабатывает с неверной логикой.
P.S. Цель запроса(при правильной логике), получить последний день месяца, следующего за месяцем в котором bornDate
#help_please

Comment: Вам нужно `получить последний день месяца` и что с ним сделать? Запрос возвращает UserBirthday с попыткой отфильтровать какие-то записи. В фильтре (т.е. в условии where) сейчас синтаксическая ошибка. Вы получаете некую дату (не ту которая вам нужна, т.е. не последний день месяца, но не это причина синтаксической ошибки), но вы ее ни с чем не сравниваете, и из-за этого ошибка. Это как если бы вы написали условие `where status`. Так что добавьте в вопрос, какие записи вы хотите вернуть и при чем тут последний день следующего месяца.

Answer (score 0):

> Цель запроса(при правильной логике), получить последний день месяца, следующего за месяцем в котором bornDate

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', bornDate) 
         + INTERVAL '2 month' 
         - INTERVAL '1 day' AS last_day of_next_month
FROM ...
```

Comment: а можно потом сравнить дату с NOW() кк примеру, в этом же запросе в условии where???

Comment: @МаксимМаксимов Да хоть два раза...